# Replacing text function value input in txt file not work

Tags: vbscript

This is my **expiration.txt** file :

```
foo1; 2020-03-01 13:33;
foo2; 2020-02-01 08:45;
foo3; 2020-01-01 11:30;
```

I need open the **expiration.txt** file and replace the all date value from:

1. **2020-03-01 13:33** to **2020-03-01**
2. **2020-02-01 08:45** to **2020-02-01**
3. **2020-01-01 11:30** to **2020-01-01**

I have tried this code without success, because the replace not working.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
' create object
set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' open the input file
set oInFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile("expiration.txt", 1)
str_input = ""
' for each line in the input file
do while not oInFile.AtEndOfStream
  ' read the line
  str_input = trim(oInFile.ReadLine())
  Wscript.echo str_input
  ' if date found then exit the loop
     if isDate(str_input) then
        WScript.echo "Date in file found: '" & str_input & "'"
        strNewText = Replace(str_input, left(str_input, 10))    
        Set objFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile("expiration.txt", 2)
        objFile.WriteLine strNewText
        WScript.echo "Date in file found: '" & strNewText & "'"
        exit do
     end if  
loop
' close the input file
oInFile.close
' release object from memory
set oFSO = nothing
```

How to do resolve this ?

Comment: You can use regular expression to resolve problems like this. You can read the entire file at once, find the required string and modify it, then save the string in the file again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expression

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
' create object
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
str_input = ""
' open the input file
Set oInFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile("expiration.txt", 1)
' read the file contents
str_input = oInFile.ReadAll()
' close the input file
oInFile.Close

' use regular expression to find and replace text
Set oRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With oRegEx
    .Multiline = True
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\s(\d+):(\d+);" 'will match entire date including ;
End With
str_input = oRegEx.Replace(str_input, "$1-$2-$3;")

' open the input file to overwrite
Set oInFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile("expiration.txt", 2)
oInFile.Write str_input
' close the input file
oInFile.Close
' release object from memory
set oFSO = nothing
```